# bluebird coroutine with node redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis, es6-promise

I'm trying to use node redis with yield and cannot find a proper way to achieve this.

Basically I want to be able to wait for the promise resolution to make my async code looks like sync code (equivalent to c# yield)

I made a simple test like this but it's not working:

```
const redisLib = require("redis")
const Promise = require("bluebird")

Promise.promisifyAll(redisLib)

var express = require('express'),
    redis = redisLib.createClient({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 }),

const redisGetYield = Promise.coroutine(function* (key) {
    const redis = app.get("redis")
    let val = yield redis.getAsync(key)
    return val
})

app.get("/test",function(req,res,next)
{
    let val = redisGetYield("test")
    return res.json({'val':val}).end()
})
```

The displayed output in my browser is :

```
{"val":{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}}
```

Looks like the yield has no effect, the code don't wait for the resolution of the promise.

I know I can use co-redis , but I want to make this with with node redis for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Have you tried using async/await? With it, you would not need to use bluebird at all. I know this isn't the answer to the question you are asking, but I think it would go far with simplifiying your code. I'll throw out an answer and you can take or leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses Node 8's `promisify`. With it, you would not need bluebird coroutine:

```
const Promise = require("bluebird")
const redis = Promise.promisifyAll(require('redis'))
const express = require('express'),

let client = redis.createClient({ 
  host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 
}));

app.get('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
    let val = await client.get('test');
    return res.json({ val }).end();
});
```

[Async/await is an extremely powerful JavaScript feature.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function) And with it, I find myself rarely using promises explicitly.

**Note:** In a production app, make sure to surround all async calls in a try catch block to catch rejected promises.

**Note 2:** I misspoke above. You will still need to use promisifyAll in bluebird. [Node 8 has a promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function, but I forgot that it only works on a single function at a time.

Comment: tried on my side in a mocha unit test and it return true instead on the key value  it("Setting a redis key", (done) =>
    {
        testApp.get("redis").set("anotherkey",5000,done)
    })     it("Redis calls with await working", async (done) =>
    {
        let val = await testApp.get("redis").get("anotherkey")
        
        console.log(val) // display true instead of 5000

        done();
    })

Comment: You need to be calling `getAsync` and `setAsync` to invoke the promisified variants of these functions. Calling `get` and `set` directly will just invoke the original variant.

Comment: ok got it , confusion between yield and await. it's working now , thanks !